# css - center an image horizontaly inside an li

Tags: css, alignment

It's amazing how can't I just pull out such a simple task.

We wish to have a menu (ul list) displayed inline, where, on top we have an image and, at the bottom, we have an anchor.

Something like the above:

```
  <iimg>    <iimg>    <iimg>
 <anchor>  <anchor>  <anchor>
```

The solution must be valid for IE 7 too.

I've tried text-align centered the image. No luck;
I've tried display:block; on the li, on -img on both... 
I've also defined widths here and there (but the images could have variable widths (not sure));
I've tried margin: 0 auto; but it centers on the page, but not on the LI. :///

Can I have a help here plz ?

http://jsfiddle.net/4E7Lu/

Comment: You can't have a 'block' element inside an 'inline' element.  Question: do you know how many ```li``` elements you'll have at the time of writing the CSS?

Comment: do you mean: an inline element can't contain a block element, even if that block element as a defined width ? - Yes I know how many li elements I will have. Let's make them 3. For the sake of argument.

Comment: The work around is ```inline-block```.  I just checked though... IE7 doesn't accept it when the element defaults to displaying block.  I'll see if I can find a fix.

Answer (score 4):

```
ul li {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Just be sure to do a clearfix after the `ul`. As in:

```
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you make the `ul` display as `inline-block`, and set the anchor and image to display as `block`, you can center them via `margin: 0 auto;`.

http://jsfiddle.net/4E7Lu/1/

Comment: IE 7 will not work there because li seems not be natural inline elements. Am I wrong ?

Comment: @MEM, sadly you're correct...  This [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4E7Lu/7/) will at least display them correctly, but won't center-align the image (In IE7 of course, it works everywhere else).

Answer (score 0):

I would apply the image as a background image to each `li` element. It's easy to position using `background-position` and keeps your HTML markup clean for SEO. You can then use [CSS sprites](http://css-tricks.com/158-css-sprites/) to make loading the images faster.

Comment: That could work actually... I wish that nothing like this arrives one day, where we have those images coming from db or so. If that happens one day, I believe we cannot use that background technique. :s

Comment: How would you place the anchor bottom and the image on top, regarding your suggestion ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just saw this, could help.

http://css.maxdesign.com.au/listamatic/horizontal01.htm